# // NOSONAR not working for Groovy language in Sonarqube version 5.3

Tags: sonarqube

// NO SONAR comment to ignore the rule for that particular code is not working. The rule is still applied for the code.

I am using Groovy plugin 1.3.1 in Sonarqube 5.3

```
Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1 // NOSONAR
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `//NOSONAR` (no space)

Comment: Modified to without space //NOSONAR, it is not working

Comment: Hmm... Then it must not be supported for Groovy